# Active areas of Research in Riemannian Geometry?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

I've taken a course in Riemannian Geometry and would like to know which topics in Riemannian Geometry are nowadys topic of research

Comment: I don't know how to be more specific

Comment: Marcos, try this open one: https://mathoverflow.net/q/449727/28128